# How do I fix this code that minuses one life from the snake in the snake game?

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to solve this code, but I need help. I want the snake to loose one life every time it hits itself or the wall. It has 3 lives. Here is my code so far:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("You will have life functions. You will get 3 lifes.\n");
char life [3];
int aa;
printf("You have 3 lifes");
printf("Press 'S' to start");
scanf("%i",&aa);

bool PlayerDied( PlayerData * pd )
{
    bool alive = false;
    --pd->Lives;       // player died - one less life
   return pd->Lives <= 0;
        alive = true;  // player still has a life left
    return alive;
}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `PlayerDied` should not have side-effects.  You can do the Lives decrement elsewhere.  Here's a one-liner for your `PlayerDied` function: `return pd->Lives <= 0;`

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to be not believing in no side-effects here. I would write this:

```
bool PlayerDied( PlayerData * pd )
{
    return (--pd->Lives) > 0;
}
```

Decrement `pd->lives` then return whether or not any lives remain.

Thre's kind of this habit in C of doing something and returning a status as the function's return value. You'll find it all over the standard APIs for various OSes.

Your mistake was having a `return` with more code after it. If the `return` is reached (and since it's unconditional it will be reached), nothing past the `;` of the return statement ever runs.